# What is the difference between various web service implementations

Tags: web-services, rest, soa

I am new to web services programming. Recently I started learning web services but there I came across various specifications like:

1. REST
2. JAX-WS
3. JAX-RPC
   etc.

Kindly update me that does these technologies occur in parallel or some are old versions and others are new versions of the same.

Also do I need to follow a hierarchy while learning these or I could start with any one randomly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are myriad of other Web Service specs such as Soap, etc. Please Google to gain a better perspective on the subject(as it is practically impossible to answer in a QA format).

Answer (score 4):

[rest](/questions/tagged/rest) is a new way of implementing and describing web services via HTTP methods and URIs. Java helps with implementing such web services with [jax-rs](/questions/tagged/jax-rs) standard. REST services are often easy to interact with using browser, `curl` or any HTTP client. See [StackOverflow API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) for an example.

[jax-ws](/questions/tagged/jax-ws) is similar to JAX-RS but provides standard way of implementing [soap](/questions/tagged/soap) web services (older but also better recognizable in industry). SOAP is much more complex than REST, all messages are sent inside XML envelope, but the protocol is not restricted to HTTP and request-response.

[jax-rpc](/questions/tagged/jax-rpc) is outdated and [currently deprecated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML-based_RPC):

> JAX-RPC 2.0 was renamed JAX-WS 2.0

Comment: REST got a Wikipedia page [8 years ago](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Representational_state_transfer&oldid=5723910), it isn't really new any more.

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz Thanks a lot for your comment it was really helping.

Answer (score 1):

REST: Representational State Transfer (REST) is a style of software architecture for distributed systems such as the World Wide Web. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Java API for XML Web Services (JAX-WS), is a set of APIs for creating web services in XML format (SOAP) mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-ws-tutorials/

JAX-RPC: Java APIs for XML-based Remote Procedure Call (JAX-RPC)
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-jaxrpc1/

As you notice from above descriptions, first one is a architecture and the rest are Jaa APIs.

You may start with REST then based on your requirement choose the API.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It helped me to startup.